# Textbox compulsory when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where add to electronic has 2 radiobuttons yes & no. And a submit button. When yes radiobutton is clicked. the quantity textbox should not be empty. But it can be empty if no radiobutton is clicked.
This functionality should work when submit button is clicked with yes radiobutton is selected.

```
 <HTML>
    <head>
    radio
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id=radio>
     Add to electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes"onclick="validate(_this)"id="yes"/>Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
    <label>Quantity</label><input type="text"size="25"name="dir"id="dir" required/> 
<button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</body>
<div>
<script src="~/Scripts/radiobuttonvalidation.js"></script>
</div>
</html>
```

I'm new to mvc and javascript. Please help me with javascript code too, and the way i should link it with my view. Javascript:

```
function validate(_this) {
    if ($(_this).attr('id') == "yes") {
        $('#dir').attr('required');
        alert("Text Box required");
    }
    else {
        $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
        alert("Text Box not required");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question description is not clear. Specify what exactly you need.

Comment: An id or name of "yes" is not a good idea, consider "dirRequired" or similar The *required* attribute should be set from the checkbox, not form submission, the logic can be `this.form.dir.required = this.form.dirRequired.checked` or similar (where *this* is the checkbox).

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues

- do not pass `_this` it is not a valid variable
- you only test one radio - so the "no" never removes the required
- your HTML is invalid - you need to close the form and not have any html other than `</html>` after the `</body>`
- You must remove the required if you want the input to be allowed empty if neither are checked

Here is a working and unobtrusive version. If you decide to use jQuery you have no reasons left to use inline event handlers

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name='yes']").on("click", function() {
    if (this.id == "yes") {
      $('#dir').attr('required', true);
      console.log("Text Box required");
    } else {
      $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
      console.log("Text Box not required");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=radio>
  Add to electronic <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes" />Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
  <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" size="25" name="dir" id="dir" />
  <button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</form>
```

RobG and I suggest to use a checkbox and I would hide the quantity to:

```js
function validate() {
  var $check = $("#addToElectronic"), checked = $check.is(":checked");
  $("#quant").toggle(checked);
  $('#dir').attr('required', checked);
}
$(function() {
  $("#addToElectronic").on("click",validate);
  validate();
});
```

```css
#quant { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=radio>
  Add to electronic <input type="checkbox" id="addToElectronic" value="yes" />Yes<br/>
  <div id="quant">
  <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" size="25" name="dir" id="dir" />
  </div>
  <button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If a checkbox is used instead of a radio, only one is required and the click listener is very simple, basically `dir.required = checkbox.checked` (as pseudo code). ;-)

Comment: Sure - that is even better - but that may not be what business wants

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your validate function only first radio button just call it on both radio button. Or you can use jQuery to add event to your radio buttons. One more thing there is no name specified in your form for radio button add one for sending data to server.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name=add_to_ele]").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="yes")
    {
      $('#dir').attr('required','required');
        alert("Text Box required");
    }
    else
    {
      $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
        alert("Text Box not required");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
Add to electronic  <input type="radio" name="add_to_ele" id="yes" value="yes"/> Yes <input value="no" type="radio" name="add_to_ele" id="no" />No<br />
    <label>Quantity</label><input type="text"size="25" name="dir" id="dir" required/> 
<button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</form >
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add validation for text box is empty or not

```js
function validate(_this) {
  if ($(_this).attr('id') == "yes") {
    if (!$('#dir').val().trim()) {
      $('#dir').attr('required');
      console.log("Text Box  required");
    }
  } else {
    $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
    console.log("Text Box not required");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=radio>
  Add to electronic <input type="radio" name="yes" onclick="validate(this)" id="yes" />Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
  <label>Quantity</label><input type="text" size="25" name="dir" id="dir" required/>
  <button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Adding the required attribute will show HTML5 error if empty - that is what SO likely wants

Comment: Your code does not stop them from adding spaces after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Typo: `onclick="validate(_this)`  this should be `onclick="validate(this)"`

```js
function validate(_this) {

    if ($(_this).attr('id') == "yes") {
        $('#dir').attr('required');
        alert("Text Box required");
    }
    else {
        $('#dir').removeAttr('required');
        alert("Text Box not required");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id=radio>
     Add to electronic  <input type="radio" name="yes"onclick="validate(this)"id="yes"/>Yes<input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" />No<br />
    <label>Quantity</label><input type="text"size="25"name="dir"id="dir"/> 
<button type=submit name=insert>insert</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Click "no" and submit after clicking yes

Comment: Still does not work. Allows me to submit when yes and nothing in the field - you need to set the required to something

Answer (score 0):

I can say that the code you have posted works fine with small changes

```js
function validate(_this) {
    if ($(_this).attr('id') == "yes") {
        $('#dir').attr('required', true);
        alert("Text Box required");
    }
    else {
        $('#dir').removeAttr('required', false);
        alert("Text Box not required");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form id="radio">
     Add to electronic  
     <input type="radio" name="yes" onclick="validate(this)" id="yes"/>Yes
     <input type="radio" name="yes" id="no" onclick="validate(this)"/> No<br />
       <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" size="25" name="dir" id="dir"/> 
    <button type="submit" name="insert">insert</button>
</form>
```

1. You have missed double quotes in form `id` and `<button>` attributes.
2. You have missed `</form>` close tag
3. `validate(_this)` inside the radio input must be `validate(this)`
4. `$('#dir').attr('required');` should be `$('#dir').attr('required', boolean_value);`

Comment: why did you change the onclick function to $("[name='yes']").on("click", function() {? We can still use onclick and try not to change maximum code of OP.

Comment: Because we should teach proper coding. If you have decided to use jQuery, you should not have inline event handlers. DRY - Do not repeat yourself.